# XML Parsing issue in python using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I do have following xml generated by some http response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response rid="1000" status="succeeded" moreData="false">
  <Results completed="true" total="25" matched="5" processed="25">
      <Resource type="h" DisplayName="Host" name="tango">
          <Time start="2011/12/16/18/46/00" end="2011/12/16/19/46/00"/>
             <PerfData attrId="cpuUsage" attrName="Usage">
                <Data intr="5" start="2011/12/16/19" end="2011/12/16/19" data="36.00"/>
                <Data intr="5" start="2011/12/16/19" end="2011/12/16/19" data="86.00"/>
                <Data intr="5" start="2011/12/16/19" end="2011/12/16/19" data="29.00"/>
             </PerfData>
          <Resource type="vm" DisplayName="VM" name="charlie" baseHost="tango">
              <Time start="2011/12/16/18/46/00" end="2011/12/16/19/46/00"/>
              <PerfData attrId="cpuUsage" attrName="Usage">
                 <Data intr="5" start="2011/12/16/19" end="2011/12/16/19" data="6.00"/>
              </PerfData>
          </Resource>
      </Resource>
  </Result>
</Response>
```

If you look at this carefully -
Outer  has one more same tag inside that

So high level xml structure is as below

```
<Resource>
    <Resource>
    </Resource>
</Resource>
```

Python ElementTree can parse only outer xml ... Below is my code

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(<Response.*?</Response>)',
                     re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

for match in pattern.finditer(data):
    contents = match.group(1)
    responses = xml.fromstring(contents)

    for results in responses:
        result = results.tag

        for resources in results:
            resource = resources.tag
            temp = {}
            temp = resources.attrib
            print temp
```

This shows following output (temp)

```
{'typeDisplayName': 'Host', 'type': 'h', 'name': 'tango'}
```

How can I fetch inner  attributes?

Comment: What do you mean by "Outer has one more same tag inside that"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse xml with regular expressions! That won't work, use some xml parsing library instead, lxml for instance:

**edit**: the code example now fetch top resources only, the loop over them and try to fetch "sub resources", this was made after OP request in comment

```
from lxml import etree

content = '''
YOUR XML HERE
'''

root = etree.fromstring(content)

# search for all "top level" resources
resources = root.xpath("//Resource[not(ancestor::Resource)]")
for resource in resources:
    # copy resource attributes in a dict
    mashup = dict(resource.attrib)
    # find child resource elements
    subresources = resource.xpath("./Resource")
    # if we find only one resource, add it to the mashup
    if len(subresources) == 1:
        mashup['resource'] = dict(subresources[0].attrib)
    # else... not idea what the OP wants...

    print mashup
```

That will output:

```
{'resource': {'DisplayName': 'VM', 'type': 'vm', 'name': 'charlie', 'baseHost': 'tango'}, 'DisplayName': 'Host', 'type': 'h', 'name': 'tango'}
```

Comment: Agreed. `etree` makes XML parsing much simpler. See [the etree documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for details.

Comment: Good catch.. However, it is inadequate.. Just take a look at this xml.. My expected dictionary would be like this - 

`
    { Resource : {'DisplayName' : 'Host' .....}, 
                  'Resource' : {'DisplayName': 'VM', ....} 
    }
`

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni that's not a valid python dict, you can't have duplicate keys

Comment: @Guillaume  My apologize... I am not aware of formatting code in comments here..

However the keys are not duplicate. There are two Keys with the same name "Resource"; one is OUTER KEY and another is INNER key..

so I would rather fetch keys as below -

resource_dict = temp['Resource']['Resource']

The above xml parsing generates all "Resource" dictionaries separate. Not as per  my expectations. I want Nested dictionary to be generated.